# Make "menu" button appear on smaller screens

Tags: html, css, menu, responsive-design

So I've made a menu that changes from being horizontal to vertical when the screen size is less than 560px. Can someone tell me how I now make the menu disappear the screen size is less than 560px and for a "MENU" button to appear instead, when button is pressed menu is to appear blow. http://ahdecor8.co.uk/menu/ If you shrink the screen size you'll see what I mean. I'm very new to coding so please explain in as simpler terms as possible :) thank you in advance!

Comment: have you had a look at media queries?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `media queries`. It would look something like this

```
@media screen and (max-width: 560px) {
    menu {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

Here's more information on media queries

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Answer (score 0):

[Media Queries](http://toddmotto.com/building-an-html5-responsive-menu-with-media-queries-javascript/) are what you're after. They allow you to specify a maximum and minimum resolution for the given layout. Once the screen size is smaller than provided, you can show a separate menu.

For example, you can either show/hide a specific menu using something like this

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  .nav-mobile {
    display:block;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  .nav-list {
    display:none;
  }
}
```

or you can modify the selectors to simply style the navigation area differently if the screen is within a given size.

Answer (score 0):

You need create another div for example:

```
<div class="example"> menu </div>

@media (max-width:560px) { 
  #bottom_nav { display: none}
  .example { display: block; background: blue; width: 100%; }
}

@media (min-width:561px) { 
  #bottom_nav { display: block;}
  .example { display: none; }
}
```